# How to tell what version of the .NET CLR is loaded by a running application on XP?

Tags: .net, version, clr-hosting

I know that there are managed shell extensions loaded by explorer.exe on a computer.  I want to know what version of the CLR is loaded into explorer.exe.  If I am running Vista or Win7, I can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and look at the .NET Assemblies tab of the properties for explorer.exe.  However, this doesn't work on XP.  Is there a way to get this info on XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't Process Explorer also show the the DLLs that have been loaded? Look for `mscorwks.dll` in that list, and see where it's being loaded from. (That's the workstation version - I can't remember what the server version is, but I don't imagine you'll see it on an XP box anyway. Look for anything beginning with `mscor` as a first approximation.)

Comment: Oh, cool.  So if I search for "mscorwks" and it lists "explorer.exe" in the results, and under Handle or DLL is shows the path it C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727, then that means definitively that it's using CLR v2.0.50727?

Comment: @Jack Smith: It means that explorer.exe has loaded CLR v2.xxx, yes. Mind you, bear in mind that CLR v4 allowed multiple versions of the CLR to be loaded in the same process...

Comment: Thanks.  If CLR 4 was running and earlier versions were also loaded, would mscorwks.dll be loaded from the v4 location?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Visual Studio installed on the target computer you can use [`clrver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427522.aspx)`<pid>` from a [Visual Studio Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx) to see what version(s) of the CLR are loaded in a process.

For example:

```
C:\>clrver 4900
v2.0.50727
```

This indicates that the process with PID 4900 has .NET 2 loaded.

```
C:\>clrver -h
Displays CLR versions
Usage: clrver [-?|-all|<PID>]

        -all   - Displays all processes on the machine using the CLR.
        <PID> - Displays the version of the CLR used by the specified process.
        -?    - Displays this help screen.

If called with no options, clrver will display all installed CLR versions.
```