# Get AppDomain for another .NET framework process

Tags: .net, debugging, process, ipc, appdomain

I am trying to get the `AppDomain` for all the .NET Framework processes running on my machine. Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: Here you have asked a question or you are ordering us to get the Values? Please, describe your Problem here.

Comment: And i tried lot to Get all app Domains which are running in .Net Framework through C# code. I welcome your suggestions.  Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: This SO question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290842/945456

Answer (score 1):

Im not entirely clear on what you are trying to do, but if you want to enumerate all running AppDomains by attaching Visual Studio to a process, see this link:
[Jack Gudenkauf "Enumerating AppDomains"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/ebf549fa-661b-4ec5-88a4-96d033892e0c/)

In that same vein, if you want to do this AT RUNTIME (without Visual Studio) then you will probably need to include a managed debugger in your program which will allow you to 'attach' to another process.
Take a look at the managed debugger example, this demonstrates a debugger, written in C#. It will then allow you to execute an 'extension' within the target application process, such as is done in Jack Gudenkauf's article.
[CLR Managed Debugger (mdbg) Sample](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&displaylang=en)

Comment: Hi Adam Yes i want to enumerate the AppDomains which are Currently running in the .Net Framework. Through VS C# i can fetch the all AppDomains which are running in the Single applciarion But not from all the applications working in .Net Framework.

Comment: I would suggest you try the approach I have mentioned, using the Managed Debugger source code. It will allow you to 'connect' to any .net process, and enumerate AppDomains.

Comment: Is there any good way to enumerate through processes to see which ones are .NET? That would make this answer even better ;)

Comment: @Jeff - Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943453/number-of-clr-and-gc-instances-running-on-a-machine - Shafqat Ahmed's answer provides a code snippet which should help.
You could also shell the 'clrver' utility as described in Daniel Fortunov's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336889/how-to-tell-what-version-of-the-net-clr-is-loaded-by-a-running-application-on-x

FYI - your comment is slightly OT ('is the CLR loaded' is different to actually getting a reference to an AppDomain) - you should post it as a new question.

Comment: Right, I think we might have a misunderstanding. Your answer discusses attaching to a process to get the `AppDomain`. I just felt that a more complete answer would include how to find which processes you need to attach to (i.e. "CLR loaded). Then again, I might be misunderstanding the process entirely ;)